# padding difference within chrome and firefox for button element

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

For the button element in Firefox the text is not centered within the element, but seems fine in Chrome. What am I doing wrong?

CSS

```
.product_add {background:#f4af40; border:none; -webkit-border-radius:3px; -moz-border-radius:3px; border-radius:3px; color:#fff; cursor:pointer; font-size:16px; padding:5px 20px;}
```

HTML

```
<input class="product_add" type="button" value="Add to Cart"/>
```

[image]

Comment: Is it the same font in both cases?

Comment: The HTML / CSS provided seems to look fine and the same in both Firefox and Chrome for me. Are there any other styles missing here?

Comment: @misterManSam is it me or the two fonts look a bit different?

Comment: @Dim13i - It looks like they are, but to me it looks like it's the same typeface with a different font weight. Might just be a trick of the eyes though!

Comment: @misterManSam exactly. Maybe this is the reason why he gets two different results.

Comment: No, its the same font. The left one is FF the right one is Chrome. I admit the font weight does look very slightly different, but it is the fact that FF has less padding on top, and more below, I cant seem to center the text in a button element.

Answer (score 0):

No, the paddings are different, the left one (presumably FF), has more bottom padding. In fact the text doesnt even appear to me in the middle of the element. Not sure what is causing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `input` to `button` and use `-moz-focus-inner` for Firefox.

```
.button::-moz-focus-inner { border: 0; padding: 0; margin:0; }
```